# Incorrect url when citing in LaTex

Tags: biblatex, citing, overleaf

I'm trying to cite with url={...} for my report. It works until I have an url that includes an underscore. For example, I'm trying to use this link: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-55220-5_9, but when I compile, Overleaf takes what comes after the underscore (so the last 9) as indice, hence it shows an incorrect link in the references.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Do not forget to add the relevant bibentry to your question ...

Comment: Do please also tell whether your document loads the `url`, `xurl`, and/o `hyperref` packages.

Comment: Most bibliography styles that support a dedicated `url` or `doi` field for URLs and DOIs, respectively, will do the right thing even for `_` if `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` is loaded (it usually does not make sense to load both those packages, since `hyperref` loads `url` internally). If this does not work for you, you may be using an unusual style or something else is wrong. Unfortunately, we can only tell you which it is when we get to see an example document that reproduces your problem and show your current bibliography setup.